# Google App Script incorrect daylight saving time

Tags: date, datetime, google-apps-script, dst

I have a Google App Script that sends me an email whenever a certain event is triggered. This script has been running fine, but today, it's not sending the email with the correct subject anymore. I am based in New Zealand and today just so happens to be our daylight saving cutover. The timezone here is GMT+12. I believe the issue is that Google App Script isn't using daylight saving, even though it is configured to.

Here's the main part of the script that generates the email subject:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+12","dd-MM-yyyy' ----------- 'EEEE' ----------- 'hh:mm a' ----------- 'ss:SS' seconds ----------- 'Z' '");
```

The output of the email subject looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the timezone is correct, but the time is not. The time should be 07:12 PM.

In the script/project, the timezone is set to the correct one. I'm not sure why the output is incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind, have solved this. Despite finding multiple answers on Google & StackOverFlow suggesting to use GMT+12, I ended up just using this:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"Pacific/Auckland","dd-MM-yyyy' ----------- 'EEEE' ----------- 'hh:mm a' ----------- 'ss:SS' seconds ----------- 'Z' '");
```